# Get Physical Address from pte value and access its value

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I got the Pte value but i am not getting the access to physical address and value at that place so please solve my problem

Code

```
pgd_t *pgd;
pud_t *pud;
pmd_t *pmd;
pte_t *pte;
unsigned long int *add;

pgd = pgd_offset(mm,address);
pud = pud_offset(pgd,address);
pmd = pmd_offset(pud,address);
pte = pte_offset_kernel(pmd,address);
add = (unsigned long int *)pte_val(*pte);
printk(KERN_INFO "\nValue at Physical Address : %lx",*add);
```

In last line it Gives me error

```
 BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 7581f448
```

give me some solution thanks in advance

Comment: can you try `pte = *pte_offset_map(pmd, address);
page = pte_page(pte);` instead of `pte_offset_kernel()`

Comment: Ya milind you are true but in mine kernel version 3.13.0-32 this macro is not available so please suggest me some other alternative and thank you for giving reply

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: thank you CL for reply but i got solution i have to use kmap to actually access the physical address. i have used it and it worked for me. Thanks a lot guys for rplying